Some Cookies are Missing in Production Environment which comes with SSO Integration
I'm experiencing an issue which is apart from the session cookie, other cookies are missing with the request. Especially, with the stauthId cookie. My setup includes a React frontend, a Node.js backend (both behind a Nginx proxy), and Single Sign-On (SSO) integration. Here’s the problem:
In my local environment, after a successful login, I can see the stauthId cookie set by SSO Provider, along with other session-related cookies.
However, in production, only the session cookie is present, and the stauthId cookie is missing along with some other cookies entirely.
Current Nginx Configuration are as follows,
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/api/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;

    proxy_set_header X-Accel-Buffering no;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_cookie;
    proxy_no_cache $http_cookie;

    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
}

I am using https and added the credentials (credentials: 'include'), but none of them worked.
Why might the stauthId cookie be missing in the production environment when it appears locally? Is this an issue related to Nginx configurations? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
